# What is the Java equivalent of Objective-C's NSDictionary?

Tags: java, objective-c, hashmap, nsdictionary

What is the closest implementation of Objective-C's `NSDictionary` in Java?  To me, it looks like `HashMap<String, Object>`, but I'm very new to Objective-C.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is a class cluster (see the "Class Cluster" section in [The Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)), meaning that the actual implementation is hidden from you, the API user. In fact, the Foundation framework will choose the appropriate implementation at run time based on amount of data etc. In addition, `NSDictionary` can take any `id` as a key, not just `NSString` (of course, the `-hash` of the key object must be constant).

Thus, closest analog is probably `Map<Object,Object>`.

Comment: Since Foundation is opensource, you can view the implementation details on apple's site too. Check under CFDictionary.c but CFDictionary.h also has some interesting documentation: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/

Answer (score 13):

For practical usage:
`HashMap<String, Object>` would be the way to go for a simple, non-parallel dictionary.
However, if you need something that is thread-safe (atomic), you'd have to use
`HashTable<String, Object>`
which is thread safe, but - notably - does not accept null as a valid value or key.

Comment: So, what's the difference to Map<Object, Object> from the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm admittedly an Android newbie, but to me [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) seems to be the closest thing to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: It's quite close but you can't store any object as values (basically you can only store numbers or strings, not complex objects)