# NSDictionary in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java equivalent of Objective-C's NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128408/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-objective-cs-nsdictionary)

I've seen other answers but they seem to squabble over each other in terms of response.

I need to translate some Objective-C and I am using NSDictionary a lot. What should I try to use in Java for this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128408/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-objective-cs-nsdictionary

Comment: Yes Hash, HashMap, Map, HashTable... hardley obvious

Comment: CS theory: computer science theory. In this case it is Intro to Java 101.

Comment: You can at last exclude Map, it's an interface (you can't create instances), and Hash class doesn't even exist, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best Java equivalent is a `Map` implementation specifically `HashMap`.